# Backbone form submission error

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I am new to Backbone, and I'm trying to get a form to submit from a tutorial.

I keep getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of undefined

for the the line `this.collection.add( book );`

What do I need to correct?

#### JavaScript:

```
App.Views.AddBook = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click #add': 'submit'
    },
    submit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = {};

        $('#addBook div').children('input').each(function(i, el) {
            if($(el).val() !== '') {
                formData[ el.id ] = $(el).val();
            }
        });

        var book = new App.Models.Book( formData );

        this.collection.add(book);
    }
});

var booksCollection = new App.Collections.Books([
    {
        title: 'JS: The Good Parts',
        author: 'Douglas Crockford',
        releaseDate: '2008'
    },
    {
        title: 'The Little Book on CoffeeScript',
        author: 'Alex MacCaw',
        releaseDate: '2012'
    }
]);

var addBook = new App.Views.AddBook({ el: $('#addBook') });
```

#### HTML:

```
<form id="addBook" action="#">
    <div>
        <label for="title">Title: </label><input id="title" type="text" />
        <label for="author">Author: </label><input id="author" type="text" />
        <label for="releaseDate">Release date: </label><input id="releaseDate" type="text" />
        <br>
        <button class="btn" id="add">Add</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass in your `booksCollection` to your view, like this:

```
var addBook = new App.Views.AddBook({ 
    collection: booksCollection,
    el: $('#addBook') 
});
```

If you don't, `this.collection` in the view context won't be defined which is why you're getting that error. The `collection` parameter in the view's initialisation is special in that Backbone will assign it to `this.collection` inside the view.